# Open my application's files in C#?

Tags: c#, executable

My application creates files with the .mhm file extension.

When one of these files are opened I want my application to start and open the file.

Right now the application starts up but the files are not opened.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the file you want to execute is the in the args parameter of your main method.

Comment: how can I give the args parameter of main method it in C# 2008?

Comment: public static void min(string[] args)
{
}