# execute my file’s Application in C#

Tags: c#, executable

My application creates files with a ".mhm" extension.

I'd like for my application to open and process these files when I double-click them. Current behavior is that when I double-click the file, my application opens but does not process the file.

How can I read the args parameter of Main() method in C# 2008?

Comment: Cleanup and Spellcheck needed on Question 1455036...

Comment: Did *anyone* understand *anything* ?

Comment: I want load my file's that save my application.what do i do?

Comment: Mohammad, you have accepted an answer to your identical question previously. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449546/execute-my-files-application-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hi

My Application creates files with the .MHM file extension.
I would like my application to be associated with this file extension so that when a MHM file is executed, my application is too, with the file path as the arguments for the main method of my application."

That's what I understood.

Grzenio has the right idea -

```
public void static Main(string args[])
{ 
...
}
```

but to push your application into the shell would take extra research, you'd have to look into integrating your application into the Shell (using the registry).

See here: [script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program#212921)

**EDIT:** Thanks for the edit of the question Chris, trying to see things a bit wider here... Perhaps the arguments solution was all the OP needed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you just use:

```
public void static Main(string args[])
{
...
}
```